# Problem passing data to function in R

Tags: r

I don't have much experience in R, so correct me if I'm making an elementary mistake:

I have a function:

```
ctree_result <- function(yval, training, testing) {
    print(yval)
    trained_tree <- ctree(formula = ordered(yval) ~ ., subset=training, data=ealls)
    print("here")
    tree_cor <- cor(yval[testing], as.numeric(predict(trained_tree, ealls[testing])))
    c_mat <- rbind(yval[testing], as.numeric(predict(trained_tree, ealls[testing])))
    tree_kappa <- cohen.kappa(t(c_mat))
    return(c(tree_cor, tree_kappa))
}
```

When I call it (with any data, but for example):

```
ctree_result(emean.data$mean.Shape, 1:70, 71:80)
```

I get the error `Error in factor(x, ..., ordered = TRUE) : object 'yval' not found`.  However, the first print statement works, the vector is printed out.  The second print statement never runs. `yval` doesn't seem to be getting passed through to ctree.

I can run the `ctree` function manually as:

```
yval <- emean.data$mean.Shape
sauc_tree = ctree(formula = ordered(yval) ~ . , data=ealls)
```

with no problems.  `ealls` and `emean.data` are global datasets I define earlier.

Comment: What does `emean.data$mean.Shape` contain?

Comment: A vector of 80 integers.

Comment: See my update.  You're probably having an issue due to lazy evaluation.  You're passing in the expression `emean.data$mean.Shape`, not the value of it.  You may need to evaluate that first with the `eval` function.

Comment: Using the `eval` function doesn't seem to work either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the `ctree` function.  The data `ealls` isn't being supplied from your parameters, so I presume that's a global dataset.  The formula is looking for a field named `yval` in the `ealls` dataset.  If you want to use the `yval` value from your function's parameter, then you should set that as the data field in `ctree`, and make sure that it has a named column for the formula.

An example of proper usage would be something like this (this is incomplete code):

```
ctree.result <- function(emean.data, ...) {
    trained_tree <- ctree(formula = ordered(mean.Shape) ~ ., subset=training, data=emean.data)
    ...
}
```

Where `emean.data` is your dataset with a column named `mean.Shape`.

I suggest that you look at `help(ctree)` and follow any supplied examples to see how that is supposed to be used.

*Edit*:

As discussed in chat, you can try to add the additional data into the dataset before calling `ctree`.  The formula expects the data to be in the dataset.

Comment: I want to change the parameter yval to modify the formula passed into the `ctree` function based on the value passed into the ctree_result. For example, run it on `mean.Shape1`, `mean.Shape2`, etc.  The `mean.Shape` columns are not in the same dataset as `ealls`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I added yval as a column to the dataset temporarily and passed in the whole dataset.  That did the trick to get rid of the error, although I have some more bugs to work out.

Answer (score 0):

A flexible solution is to create a formula that contains the name of the variable that you are actually going to use. Here is a reproducible example using the `lm` function:

```
lm_result <- function(yvar){
  fla <- as.formula(paste(yvar, " ~ Species"))
  lm(fla, data=iris)
}

lm_result("Petal.Length")
```

Note that you have to pass the name of the variable instead of the variable itself for this approach.

Comment: @Shane Yes, I am suggesting he change that. I don't see anything in the description that would require passing the variable itself.

Comment: @Shane Oh, you mean the variable is not even _in_ the data set. I missed that part.